# Ruby on Rails Multiple search query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have to modify a search in the home page of a site. The code is written in Ruby language and used "Rails" frame work.

***Image******

[image]

Here, there is already an option for search with mail id. But there is an id field too. Need to implement multiple search.

Already written code of "view" (MVC architecture):-

```
 <form action="/users/search" method="POST">
   <label for="email">Email</label>
   <input type="text" name="email" />&nbsp;
   <input type="submit" name="search" value="Search" />
   <input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="<%= form_authenticity_token %>" />
 </form>
```

Already written code of its "controller" (MVC architecture):-

```
 def search 
    @users = User.paginate(
            :conditions => ["email LIKE ?", '%' + params[:email] + '%'], 
            :page => params[:page], :per_page => 25, 
            :order => params[:order].nil? ? 
            :email :  params[:order].gsub('-', ' ')
            )

   if @users.length == 1
     redirect_to edit_user_path(@users.first)
   else
     render "index"
   end
  end
```

- Please help me to **use multiple search with the condition** in controller file satisfying these:-
- Search with id
- Search with email (already written)
- Search with email and id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the view section

```
<form action="/users/search" method="POST">
       <label for="email">Email</label>
       <input type="text" name="email" />&nbsp;
       <label for="user_id">ID</label>
       <input type="text" name="user_id" />&nbsp;
       <input type="submit" name="search" value="Search" />
       <input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="<%= form_authenticity_token %>" />
</form>
```

In the search action

```
@users = User.paginate(
            :conditions => ["email LIKE ? or id = ?", '%' + params[:email] + '%', params[:user_id]], 
            :page => params[:page], :per_page => 25, 
            :order => params[:order].nil? ? 
            :email :  params[:order].gsub('-', ' ')
            )
```

it will search the records with id, email and id or email.